# How can I get data from a program?

Tags: c

How can I retrieve the data it contains from a running program? And can I interfere with the program? For example, can I change the variables?

For example:

Runnning program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int a = 0;

        while (1){
                ++a;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Imagine this program running on my computer all the time. Now can I get the value of the variable "a" in this program using another C code? And, for example, can I replace it with a value of 100?

Comment: With a debugger.

Comment: With a debugger, with shared memory, with interprocess communication, with threads, etc. It highly depends on the situation.

Comment: One common way is to communicate with the outside is using _files_. It's not optimal for such a tight loop that you have, but you can write your current value of `a` to a file and read input values from a file.

Comment: The two comments above are assuming the program in question is *designed* to communicate with the user, and is "willingly" outputting the data in an accessible way. Unlike the program presented in the question.

Comment: Actually i am thinking of storing data in ram. I can add a control to the loop. for example keypress. But I don't want to.

Comment: If you are using the Microsoft Windows platform, then you may want to take a look at this: [Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) Other platforms have similar functionality.

Comment: Are you talking about two programs cooperating? Or are you talking about one program manipulating another program without that program's cooperation?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Manipulating another program.

Comment: Which platform are you using? Microsoft Windows? Linux?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Linux - Debian 11

Comment: Do you have the source code of the target program? Or are you trying to manipulate third-party closed-source software?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Code belongs to me. I did some research and found out that I can access the section that the operating system has reserved for me. I think they call it "Memory protection".

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? Why not write the program in such a way that it will output its values instead of trying to "steal" them?

Comment: As far as I can tell, a debugger should be able to do everything you mentioned.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just wondered. I already have a control blog in my code.

Comment: Could you please provide a link with more detailed information?

Comment: Why don't you explain what you are trying to achieve, without mentioning or focussing on any specific implementation you had in mind.

Comment: The most popular debugger for Linux seems to be [GDB: The GNU Project Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). However, many [IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) provide graphical front-ends and only use GDB as a back-end. Therefore, you may want to consult your IDE's documentation on how to use the debugger or how to install one.

Comment: You can also attach to a running process with `strace` (as root) providing the PID to attach to and monitor what the code is doing. In your code above, if optimizations are used, the entire code is likely optimized away as there are no meaningful side-effects produced by your program.

Answer (score 0):

the most ideal way to perform this kind of things WHILE running the program is by the debugger.
you can try to put breaking points as well on your code but I will prefer using just the "step" button and run this program manually.
Take care,
Ori